# Packages Are not Importing on Docker even though they seem to be installed

Tags: django, docker

I have tried installing new packaged. they all seem to load without and issue but somehow they are not importing. I have tried docker-compose build to no avail. They show up on pip freeze. My guess is somehow these are not loaded on my docker container but I am not sure what else to do. Sorry if my question is too elementary for this sub. I am a CS major and this is our first large project working with backend and frontend and I have stayed up all night trying to figure this up but I am lost I feel. Thanks for your help.

Here are some of the packages in question

```
drf-spectacular
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
django-address
here is the content of my requirement.txt:
Django>=3.2.4,<3.3
djangorestframework>=3.12.4,<3.13
psycopg2>=2.8.6,<2.9
drf-spectacular>=0.15.1,<0.16
```

here is what I have under registered apps

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'core',
'rest_framework',
'rest_framework.authtoken',
'drf_spectacular',
'user',
'address',
'phonenumber_field',
```

pip freeze shows the following

Mobile>pip freeze

```
absl-py==1.0.0
alabaster @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/alabaster_1611921544520/work
anaconda-client @ file:///C:/ci/anaconda-client_1635342725944/work
anaconda-navigator==2.1.1
anaconda-project @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/anaconda-project_1626085644852/work
anyio @ file:///C:/ci/anyio_1620153135622/work/dist
appdirs==1.4.4
argh==0.26.2
argon2-cffi @ file:///C:/ci/argon2-cffi_1613037869401/work
arrow @ file:///C:/ci/arrow_1617738834352/work
asgiref==3.5.2
asn1crypto @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/asn1crypto_1596577642040/work
astroid @ file:///C:/ci/astroid_1628063282661/work
astropy @ file:///C:/ci/astropy_1629829318700/work
astunparse==1.6.3
async-generator @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/async_generator_1611927993394/work
atomicwrites==1.4.0
attrs @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/attrs_1620827162558/work
autopep8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/autopep8_1620866417880/work
awsebcli==3.20.3
Babel @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/babel_1620871417480/work
backcall @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/backcall_1611930011877/work
backports.functools-lru-cache @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.functools_lru_cache_1618170165463/work
backports.shutil-get-terminal-size @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/backports.shutil_get_terminal_size_1608222128777/work
backports.tempfile @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/backports.tempfile_1610991236607/work
backports.weakref==1.0.post1
bcrypt @ file:///C:/ci/bcrypt_1607022693089/work
beautifulsoup4 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/beautifulsoup4_1631874778482/work
binaryornot @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/binaryornot_1617751525010/work
bitarray @ file:///C:/ci/bitarray_1629133068652/work
bkcharts==0.2
black==19.10b0
bleach @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/bleach_1628110601003/work
bokeh @ file:///C:/ci/bokeh_1635306491714/work
boto==2.49.0
botocore==1.23.54
Bottleneck @ file:///C:/ci/bottleneck_1607557040328/work
brotlipy==0.7.0
cached-property @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cached-property_1600785575025/work
cachetools==5.0.0
cement==2.8.2
certifi==2022.6.15
cffi==1.15.1
chardet @ file:///C:/ci/chardet_1607706937985/work
charset-normalizer==2.0.12
click==8.0.3
cloudpickle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cloudpickle_1632508026186/work
clyent==1.2.2
colorama @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/colorama_1607707115595/work
comtypes==1.1.10
conda==4.12.0
conda-build==3.21.6
conda-content-trust @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-content-trust_1617045594566/work
conda-pack @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-pack_1611163042455/work
conda-package-handling @ file:///C:/ci/conda-package-handling_1618262410900/work
conda-repo-cli @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-repo-cli_1620168426516/work
conda-token @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/conda-token_1620076980546/work
conda-verify==3.4.2
contextlib2 @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/contextlib2_1630668244042/work
cookiecutter @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/cookiecutter_1617748928239/work
cryptography @ file:///C:/ci/cryptography_1633520531101/work
cycler==0.10.0
Cython @ file:///C:/ci/cython_1636018292912/work
cytoolz==0.11.0
daal4py==2021.3.0
dask==2021.10.0
debugpy @ file:///C:/ci/debugpy_1629222819322/work
decorator @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/decorator_1632776554403/work
defusedxml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/defusedxml_1615228127516/work
diff-match-patch @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/diff-match-patch_1630511840874/work
dill @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/dill_1623919422540/work
distlib==0.3.6
distributed @ file:///C:/ci/distributed_1635968318313/work
Django==4.1
django-address==0.2.8
django-phonenumber-field==6.4.0
djangorestframework==3.13.1
docutils @ file:///C:/ci/docutils_1620828264669/work
drf-spectacular==0.15.0
echo @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/echo_1614170694720/work
elastic-transport==8.1.2
elasticsearch==8.3.1
entrypoints==0.3
et-xmlfile==1.1.0
fast-histogram @ file:///C:/ci/fast-histogram_1614080245740/work
fastcache @ file:///C:/ci/fastcache_1607571310570/work
filelock==3.8.0
flake8 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/flake8_1620776156532/work
Flask @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/flask_1611932660458/work
flatbuffers==1.12
fonttools==4.25.0
fsspec @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/fsspec_1636116461911/work
future @ file:///C:/ci/future_1607568713721/work
gast==0.4.0
gevent @ file:///C:/ci/gevent_1628273776273/work
glob2 @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/glob2_1610991677669/work
glue-core @ file:///C:/ci/glue-core_1625841943868/work
glue-vispy-viewers==0.12.2
glueviz @ file:///C:/ci/glueviz_1600379030367/work
google-auth==2.6.4
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.6
google-pasta==0.2.0
greenlet @ file:///C:/ci/greenlet_1628888275363/work
grpcio==1.44.0
h5py @ file:///C:/ci/h5py_1622088609188/work
HeapDict @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/heapdict_1630598515714/work
html5lib @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/html5lib_1629144453894/work
idna==3.3
imagecodecs @ file:///C:/ci/imagecodecs_1635511087451/work
imageio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/imageio_1617700267927/work
imagesize @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/imagesize_1628863108022/work
imbalanced-learn==0.9.0
importlib-metadata @ file:///C:/ci/importlib-metadata_1631916826748/work
inflection==0.5.1
iniconfig @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/iniconfig_1610983019677/work
intervaltree @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/intervaltree_1630511889664/work
ipykernel @ file:///C:/ci/ipykernel_1633545585502/work/dist/ipykernel-6.4.1-py3-none-any.whl
ipython @ file:///C:/ci/ipython_1635944283918/work
ipython-genutils @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ipython_genutils_1606773439826/work
ipywidgets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ipywidgets_1634143127070/work
isort @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/isort_1628603791788/work
itsdangerous @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/itsdangerous_1621432558163/work
jdcal @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/jdcal_1630584345063/work
jedi @ file:///C:/ci/jedi_1611341083684/work
Jinja2 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jinja2_1612213139570/work
jinja2-time @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jinja2-time_1617751524098/work
jmespath==0.10.0
joblib @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/joblib_1635411271373/work
json5 @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/json5_1624432770122/work
jsonschema @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/jsonschema_1630511932244/work
jupyter @ file:///C:/ci/jupyter_1607685287094/work
jupyter-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_client_1616770841739/work
jupyter-console @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyter_console_1616615302928/work
jupyter-core @ file:///C:/ci/jupyter_core_1633420716440/work
jupyter-server @ file:///C:/ci/jupyter_server_1616084298419/work
jupyterlab @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_1635799997693/work
jupyterlab-pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_pygments_1601490720602/work
jupyterlab-server @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_server_1633419203660/work
jupyterlab-widgets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/jupyterlab_widgets_1609884341231/work
keras==2.9.0
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
keyring @ file:///C:/ci/keyring_1629321702436/work
kiwisolver @ file:///C:/ci/kiwisolver_1612282555033/work
lazy-object-proxy @ file:///C:/ci/lazy-object-proxy_1616529288960/work
libarchive-c @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-libarchive-c_1617780486945/work
libclang==13.0.0
llvmlite==0.37.0
locket==0.2.1
lxml @ file:///C:/ci/lxml_1616443418777/work
Markdown==3.3.6
MarkupSafe @ file:///C:/ci/markupsafe_1607027406824/work
matplotlib @ file:///C:/ci/matplotlib-suite_1634667159685/work
matplotlib-inline @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/matplotlib-inline_1628242447089/work
mccabe==0.6.1
menuinst @ file:///C:/ci/menuinst_1631733438520/work
missingno==0.5.0
mistune @ file:///C:/ci/mistune_1607359457024/work
mkl-fft==1.3.1
mkl-random @ file:///C:/ci/mkl_random_1626186184308/work
mkl-service==2.4.0
mock @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/mock_1607622725907/work
more-itertools @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/more-itertools_1635423142362/work
mpl-scatter-density @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/mpl-scatter-density_1596880069366/work
mpmath==1.2.1
msgpack @ file:///C:/ci/msgpack-python_1612287350784/work
multipledispatch @ file:///C:/ci/multipledispatch_1607574329826/work
munkres==1.1.4
mypy-extensions==0.4.3
navigator-updater==0.2.1
nbclassic @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbclassic_1616085367084/work
nbclient @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbclient_1614364831625/work
nbconvert==6.4.2
nbformat @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nbformat_1617383369282/work
nest-asyncio @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nest-asyncio_1613680548246/work
networkx @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/networkx_1633639043937/work
nltk==3.6.5
nose @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/nose_1606773131901/work
notebook @ file:///C:/ci/notebook_1635393701545/work
numba @ file:///C:/ci/numba_1635186062888/work
numexpr @ file:///C:/ci/numexpr_1618856728739/work
numpy @ file:///C:/ci/numpy_and_numpy_base_1626271900803/work
numpydoc @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/numpydoc_1605117425582/work
oauthlib==3.2.0
olefile @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/olefile_1629805411829/work
opencv-python==4.5.5.64
openpyxl @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/openpyxl_1632777717936/work
opt-einsum==3.3.0
packaging @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/packaging_1625611678980/work
pandas @ file:///D:/bld/pandas_1648901014223/work
pandocfilters @ file:///C:/ci/pandocfilters_1605114832805/work
paramiko @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/paramiko_1598886428689/work
parso @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/parso_1617223946239/work
partd @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/partd_1618000087440/work
path @ file:///C:/ci/path_1624287837534/work
pathlib2 @ file:///C:/ci/pathlib2_1625585796814/work
pathspec==0.9.0
patsy==0.5.2
pep8==1.7.1
pexpect @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pexpect_1605563209008/work
phonenumbers==8.12.54
pickleshare @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pickleshare_1606932040724/work
Pillow==8.4.0
pkginfo==1.7.1
platformdirs==2.5.2
plotly @ file:///opt/conda/conda-bld/plotly_1646671701182/work
pluggy @ file:///C:/ci/pluggy_1615976440052/work
ply==3.11
poyo @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/poyo_1617751526755/work
prometheus-client @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prometheus_client_1623189609245/work
prompt-toolkit @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/prompt-toolkit_1633440160888/work
protobuf==3.19.4
psutil @ file:///C:/ci/psutil_1612298199233/work
ptyprocess @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/ptyprocess_1609355006118/work/dist/ptyprocess-0.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
py @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/py_1607971587848/work
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
pycodestyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycodestyle_1615748559966/work
pycosat==0.6.3
pycparser @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pycparser_1594388511720/work
pycurl==7.44.1
pydocstyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pydocstyle_1621600989141/work
pyerfa @ file:///C:/ci/pyerfa_1621560974055/work
pyflakes @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyflakes_1617200973297/work
Pygments @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pygments_1629234116488/work
PyJWT @ file:///C:/ci/pyjwt_1619682721924/work
pylint @ file:///C:/ci/pylint_1627536884966/work
pyls-spyder==0.4.0
PyNaCl @ file:///C:/ci/pynacl_1607612759007/work
pyodbc===4.0.0-unsupported
PyOpenGL==3.1.1a1
pyOpenSSL @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyopenssl_1635333100036/work
pyparsing @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/pyparsing_1635766073266/work
pypiwin32==223
pyreadline==2.1
pyrsistent @ file:///C:/ci/pyrsistent_1636093225342/work
PySocks @ file:///C:/ci/pysocks_1605307512533/work
pytest==6.2.4
python-dateutil @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-dateutil_1626374649649/work
python-lsp-black @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-lsp-black_1634232156041/work
python-lsp-jsonrpc==1.0.0
python-lsp-server==1.2.4
python-slugify @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/python-slugify_1620405669636/work
python-utils==3.1.0
pytz==2021.3
PyWavelets @ file:///C:/ci/pywavelets_1607645631519/work
pywin32==304
pywin32-ctypes @ file:///C:/ci/pywin32-ctypes_1607553594546/work
pywinpty @ file:///C:/ci/pywinpty_1607419945780/work
PyYAML==6.0
pyzmq @ file:///C:/ci/pyzmq_1628276105793/work
QDarkStyle @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qdarkstyle_1617386714626/work
qstylizer @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qstylizer_1617713584600/work/dist/qstylizer-0.1.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl
QtAwesome @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtawesome_1615991616277/work
qtconsole @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtconsole_1632739723211/work
QtPy @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/qtpy_1629397026935/work
regex @ file:///C:/ci/regex_1628063427816/work
requests @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/requests_1629994808627/work
requests-oauthlib==1.3.1
rope @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/rope_1623703006312/work
rsa==4.8
Rtree @ file:///C:/ci/rtree_1618421015405/work
ruamel-yaml-conda @ file:///C:/ci/ruamel_yaml_1616016898638/work
scikit-image==0.18.3
scikit-learn==1.0.2
scikit-learn-intelex==2021.20210714.120553
scipy @ file:///C:/ci/scipy_1630606917240/work
seaborn @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/seaborn_1629307859561/work
semantic-version==2.8.5
Send2Trash @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/send2trash_1632406701022/work
simplegeneric==0.8.1
singledispatch @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/singledispatch_1629321204894/work
sip==4.19.13
six @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/six_1623709665295/work
sniffio @ file:///C:/ci/sniffio_1614030527509/work
snowballstemmer @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/snowballstemmer_1611258885636/work
sortedcollections @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sortedcollections_1611172717284/work
sortedcontainers @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sortedcontainers_1623949099177/work
soupsieve @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/soupsieve_1616183228191/work
Sphinx==4.2.0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/sphinxcontrib-applehelp_1611920841464/work
sphinxcontrib-devhelp @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/sphinxcontrib-devhelp_1611920923094/work
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp_1623945626792/work
sphinxcontrib-jsmath @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/sphinxcontrib-jsmath_1611920942228/work
sphinxcontrib-qthelp @ file:///home/ktietz/src/ci/sphinxcontrib-qthelp_1611921055322/work
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml_1624451540180/work
sphinxcontrib-websupport @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/sphinxcontrib-websupport_1597081412696/work
spyder @ file:///C:/ci/spyder_1636480369575/work
spyder-kernels @ file:///C:/ci/spyder-kernels_1634237096710/work
SQLAlchemy @ file:///C:/ci/sqlalchemy_1626948551162/work
sqlparse==0.4.2
statsmodels==0.12.2
sympy @ file:///C:/ci/sympy_1635219088507/work
tables==3.6.1
TBB==0.2
tblib @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/tblib_1629402031467/work
tenacity @ file:///C:/ci/tenacity_1626248381338/work
tensorboard==2.9.0
tensorboard-data-server==0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.8.1
tensorflow==2.9.1
tensorflow-estimator==2.9.0
tensorflow-gpu==2.9.1
tensorflow-io-gcs-filesystem==0.24.0
termcolor==1.1.0
terminado==0.9.4
testpath @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/testpath_1624638946665/work
text-unidecode @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/text-unidecode_1629401354553/work
textdistance @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/textdistance_1612461398012/work
tf-estimator-nightly==2.8.0.dev2021122109
threadpoolctl @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/threadpoolctl_1629802263681/work
three-merge @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/three-merge_1607553261110/work
tifffile @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tifffile_1627275862826/work
tinycss @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tinycss_1617713798712/work
toml @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/toml_1616166611790/work
toolz @ file:///home/linux1/recipes/ci/toolz_1610987900194/work
tornado @ file:///C:/ci/tornado_1606924294691/work
tqdm @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/tqdm_1635330843403/work
traitlets @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/traitlets_1632522747050/work
typed-ast @ file:///C:/ci/typed-ast_1624953797214/work
typing-extensions @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/typing_extensions_1631814937681/work
tzdata==2022.2
ujson @ file:///C:/ci/ujson_1611259568517/work
unicodecsv==0.14.1
Unidecode @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/unidecode_1614712377438/work
uritemplate==4.1.1
urllib3==1.26.12
virtualenv==20.16.3
watchdog @ file:///C:/ci/watchdog_1624955113064/work
wcwidth @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/wcwidth_1629357192024/work
webencodings==0.5.1
Werkzeug @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/werkzeug_1635505089296/work
whichcraft @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/whichcraft_1617751293875/work
widgetsnbextension @ file:///C:/ci/widgetsnbextension_1607531582688/work
win-inet-pton @ file:///C:/ci/win_inet_pton_1605306162074/work
win-unicode-console==0.5
wincertstore==0.2
wordcloud==1.8.1
wrapt @ file:///C:/ci/wrapt_1607574570428/work
xgboost==1.6.1
xlrd==2.0.1
XlsxWriter @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/xlsxwriter_1628603415431/work
xlwings==0.24.9
xlwt==1.3.0
xmltodict @ file:///Users/ktietz/demo/mc3/conda-bld/xmltodict_1629301980723/work
yapf @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/yapf_1615749224965/work
zict==2.0.0
zipp @ file:///tmp/build/80754af9/zipp_1633618647012/work
zope.event==4.5.0

    zope.interface @ file:///C:/ci/zope.interface_1625036252485/work
```

'''

Comment: How are you installing those libraries, is it `apt-get` or `pip`?

Comment: hi Fareed , I used pip

Comment: You should check all the possible solution mentioned in this article: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/importerror-docker/